Is もの間 parsed as 物 + 間 or も particle + の particle + 間?
For example in a sentence from a Japanese grammar tutorial:


その殺人事件の容疑者は10年もの間（を）、息を潜めて、隠れていました。
The suspect of that murder case had been hiding, breath bated, for ten years.


Here I'm tempted to parse もの間 as "even (も) a ten year period (10年...の間)". That is to say, もの here is just も＋の particles, and bears no relation to 物. Is this the case?

If by parsing it as "物 + 間" you are referring to this word 物間{ものあい}, it perhaps helps to keep in mind that that is an exceedingly rare word and doesn't occur in everyday Japanese. When you see or hear もの間 you can safely assume it's particle も + particle の + noun 間{あいだ}. And going by your question post's content I think you understand what it means, so I won't explain that part.

It is も+の and has no connection to 物. Whenever you see “quantity”+も, just know that the も is there to emphasise that said quantity is “a lot”. Here  it is emphasising that 10 years is a long time.
Removing the も yields simply 10年の間, which I’m sure you are familiar with.
